# Can't initialize a new Group

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm using some the standard AclExtras plugin setup and everything works as is. However, I've added a new group and when I re-run initDB() it dies when reaching the new group id -

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] => Group [Aro0.foreign_key] => 6 )
```

I've also tried running aco_sync from the console just to see it had any effect - and it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error message, what I had done was create a bunch of groups first, then deleted some. So there was no group with id=1. If you go to the db and check the group id's, those are the ones you should use to populate your ACL.